# Tabela não quer ficar na vertical

Tags: html, python-3.x, table, flask

Queria saber o que estou fazendo de errado, pois criei uma tabela no template pegando informação de uma api. Queria que ordenar-se na vertical e não na orizontal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    <!Doctepy html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Teste de Requests</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th bgcolor="red">Pilotos</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                {% for i in range(200) %}
                    {% if "IFATC" in data[i]['DisplayName'] %}
                        <td align= middle width=100>{{data[i]['DisplayName']}}</td>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para cada linha da tabela você deve ter também um TR (table row) próprio:

```
{% for i in range(200) %}
    {% if "IFATC" in data[i]['DisplayName'] %}
    <tr>
        <td align=middle width=100>{{data[i]['DisplayName']}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Ou seja, coloque os TR dentro do laço para que eles também sejam repetidos.

Uma dica, evite usar os atributos de formatação direto nas tags HTML e faça a formatação diretamente usando CSS, a manutenção do código e alterações de leiaute ficarão bem mais simples.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, com a sua dica resolvi o problema

Answer (score -1):

É muito simples, amigo. O código na estrutura abaixo vai gerar uma tabela horizontal. Cada novo bloco de códigos TR vai gerar uma linha com células.

```
<tr>
       <td></td>
             ...
         <td></td>
</tr>
```

Já no código seguinte, teremos cada novo bloco TR contendo uma única célula, vai gerar uma tabela vertical.

```
<tr>
       <td></td>
</tr>
      ...
<tr>
       <td></td>
</tr>
```

Mas a tabela vertical pode ter mais de uma célula também. Então, como o amigo disse acima, dependendo de como você faz o laço, o resultado pode variar.